# ALL vs ANY evaluation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm just trying out now the below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT code,
                CASE
                  WHEN id = ANY (SELECT DISTINCT u.id
                                 FROM   unit u
                                        LEFT JOIN unit_const uc
                                               ON u.id = uc.hid
                                 WHERE  u.property = 502
                                        AND type = 'Acq') THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
                END                       AS Case_Eval,
                (SELECT DISTINCT u.id
                 FROM   unit u
                        LEFT JOIN unit_const uc
                               ON u.id = uc.hid
                 WHERE  u.property = 502
                        AND type = 'Acq') AS Evaluation
FROM   unit
WHERE  property = 502
```

which correctly gives the below result:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Code       Case_Eval   Evaluation     |
+---------------------------------------+
| TP2_U1     0           NULL           |
| TP2_U2     0           NULL           |
| TP2_U3     0           NULL           |
| TP2_U4     0           NULL           |
+---------------------------------------+
```

But if I switch from `ANY` to `ALL` then the `CASE` statement is evaluated to 1.

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Code       Case_Eval   Evaluation     |
+---------------------------------------+
| TP2_U1     1           NULL           |
| TP2_U2     1           NULL           |
| TP2_U3     1           NULL           |
| TP2_U4     1           NULL           |
+---------------------------------------+
```

But as you can see the SELECT statement that returns the value to be compared in the `CASE` is `NULL` all the time.

How can the `CASE` statement evaluate this to true? The unit `ID` is not `NULL` (they are 601, 602, 603 and 604 for the 4 units), so how when compared to `ALL(NULL)` is results into true?

Is there something incorrect in my understanding?

As per [ALL documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx) it evaluates a scalar value to a list of values.

And it returns true if:

"**Returns TRUE when the comparison specified is TRUE for all pairs (scalar_expression, x), when x is a value in the single-column set; otherwise returns FALSE.**"

How can pair(601, NULL) evaluate to True?

Comment: +1 for introducing some syntax I never realised existed in T-SQL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id
FROM   unit u
       LEFT JOIN unit_const uc
         ON u.id = uc.hid
WHERE  u.property = 502
       AND type = 'Acq'
```

The above statement must return zero rows. Not null. A sub query that returns zero rows is given a value of `NULL` when used in a scalar fashion (as with your "Evaluation" column) but the sub query itself doesn't return that.

The SQL Standard defines different behaviour for `ALL` and `ANY` (AKA `SOME`) when it comes to comparing against empty sets.

For `ALL` the comparison evaluates to `true`

```
If T is empty or if the implied <comparison predicate> is true for every row RT 
in T, then "R <comp op> <all> T" is true.
```

This is per classical logic where the statements "all cell phones in the room are turned off" and "all cell phones in the room are turned on" are both regarded as true ([though vacuously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)) if the room has no cell phones.

For `Any`/`Some` there must be at least one pair that actually matches.

The relevant bit of the SQL Standard for that is below.

```
If T is empty or if the implied <comparison predicate> is false for every row RT 
in T, then "R <comp op> <some> T" is false.
```

Comment: But how can an empty set evaluate to true when compared with an integer?

Comment: The value you are comparing does match all members of the set if that set is empty.

Comment: I still can't get my head around why `601 = NULL` is TRUE and returns a 1. But `SELECT CASE WHEN 1 = NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` will return a 0.

Comment: It never does a comparison to null. No nulls are involved. The confusion is that a subquery that returns nothing is then given a value of null in your evaluation column.

Comment: I now understand and agree with you. But still, I don't think it's correct to evaluate a value with an empty set as TRUE.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu this is per the SQL Standard.

Comment: Do you have any references for this? I'd like to take a look for myself. I'd like to undestand why this has been set as a standard. Maybe some mathematical explanations or otherwise.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - "If T is empty or if the implied <comparison predicate> is
              true for every row RT in T, then "R <comp op> <all> T" is
              true." [SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - [This is a vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)