# Comparing two variables in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Lets say you have the next code:

```
DECLARE @A INT = 1,
        @B INT = NULL;

IF (@B != @A)
    SELECT 1;
ELSE IF (@B = @A)
    SELECT 2;
ELSE
    SELECT 3;
```

As you can see variable `@A` equals *'1'* for sure and variable `@B` certainly doesn't. I'm executing that part of code in *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014* and I'm getting *'3'* as result. That means `@A` is not the same as `@B`, but it's also not different than `@B`. How is that even possible? What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing an understanding of `NULL` values.  Almost any comparison with `NULL` returns `NULL`, which is treated as false.  This is covered both in learning material on SQL, documentation, and in other Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: Another good/cool thing to know and understand about comparing with `NULL` values can be found in this [awesome answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26551761/1266737).

Comment: The only way to compare NULL is with the `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL` operators

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, guess I missed some basic stuff. =/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot compare null with other values. You need to handle nulls separately.
So,this will work

```
DECLARE @A INT = 1,
        @B INT = NULL;

IF (@B != @A or @B is  null )
    SELECT 1;
ELSE IF (@B = @A)
    SELECT 2;
ELSE
    SELECT 3;
```

Comment: why dont you check if @A is null ?

Comment: I explained why his code didn't work. my answer is more specific to his input data.

Answer (score 2):

The correct version should be:

```
IF (@B = @A OR (@B IS NULL AND @A IS NULL))
    SELECT 2;
ELSE IF (@B != @A OR @B IS NULL OR @A IS NULL)
    SELECT 1;
ELSE
    SELECT 3;
```

because NULL comparison must always be handled separately in SQL.

I inverted the `!=` and the `=` cases because tsql doesn't have a logical XOR operator, because I want to consider NULL equal to NULL.

Note that then the `SELECT 3` won't ever happen now.

Answer (score 1):

I always use ISNULL function. I think ISNULL function saves you from writing longer scripts.

```
DECLARE @A INT = 1,
        @B INT = NULL;

IF (ISNULL(@B,0) != ISNULL(@A,0))
    SELECT 1;
ELSE IF (@B = @A)
    SELECT 2;
ELSE
    SELECT 3;
```

Comment: You are using a value inside the domain of possible values in the `ISNULL()`. @A = 1, @B = NULL returns `SELECT 1`, while @A = 0, @B = NULL returns `SELECT 3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily compare variables using `INTERSECT` as it is `NULL`-sensitive:

```
DECLARE @A BIT = NULL
       ,@B BIT = 1;

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT @A
    INTERSECT 
    SELECT @B
)
    SELECT 'equal';
ELSE
    SELECT 'not equal';
```

Also, when you need to do such comparisons in complex queries, this could improve performance as it allows using indexes.