# SQL Server ALL subquery with no rows, how to force false?

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I'm grasping for syntax that would get me the performance of ALL, while excluding the parent rows with no children (failed subquery.)

```
CREATE TABLE #Parts 
(
    Part varchar(64) not null
)

INSERT INTO #Parts VALUES('Test One')
INSERT INTO #Parts VALUES('Test Two')
INSERT INTO #Parts VALUES('Test Three')

CREATE TABLE #Attr 
(
    Part varchar(64) not null,
    Attr varchar(8) not null
)

INSERT INTO #Attr VALUES('Test One','123P4567')
INSERT INTO #Attr VALUES('Test One','987P4567')
INSERT INTO #Attr VALUES('Test Two','123P4567')
INSERT INTO #Attr VALUES('Test Two','987X4567')

SELECT * 
FROM #Parts p
WHERE 'P' = ANY (SELECT SUBSTRING(a.Attr, 4, 1) 
                 FROM #Attr a 
                 WHERE a.Part = p.Part)

SELECT * 
FROM #Parts p
WHERE 'P' = ALL (SELECT SUBSTRING(a.Attr, 4, 1) 
                 FROM #Attr a 
                 WHERE a.Part = p.Part)

SELECT * 
FROM #Parts p
WHERE 'P' = ALL (SELECT SUBSTRING(a.Attr, 4, 1) 
                 FROM #Attr a 
                 WHERE a.Part = p.Part)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT a.Part FROM #Attr a WHERE a.Part = p.Part)
```

- The first query returns one and two as expected
- The second query returns one and three (per SQL standard).
- The third query returns one, the desired result.

When I use ALL and EXISTS together (third query) in my large data set, the query goes from milliseconds to 60 seconds.  Is there some way to alter the ALL syntax to give false on the failed subquery for 'Test Three'?

This related question helped me understand why the second query gives results other than I expected:

[ALL vs ANY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551394/all-vs-any-evaluation-in-sql-server)

Comment: This inner join also excludes Three, and is much faster than exists, but causes multiple updates.  


 select * from #Parts p
 inner join #Attr a on a.Part = p.Part
 where 'P' = ALL (select SUBSTRING(a.Attr, 4, 1) from #Attr a where a.Part = p.Part)

Answer (score 1):

You could rework the `ALL` to a `NOT EXISTS`.

Instead of saying:

> all related records must have 'P' as 4th character

You could say:

> no related records can have anything different than 'P' as 4th character

The output of the implementation below matches the output of your third (desired) result query. Performance validation is much harder with your full data set.

```
select *
from #Parts p
where exists (  select 'x'
                from #Attr a
                where a.Part = p.Part)
  and not exists (  select 'x'
                    from #Attr a
                    where a.Part = p.Part
                      and substring(a.Attr, 4, 1) <> 'P' )
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have tried the exists and not exists and get the bad performance I get with All and Exists.